# Can't launch MySQL Workbench v6.3.8

Tags: mysql-workbench

I've seen similar posts regarding this issue on the site, but none of the posted resolutions worked for me.  When I attempt to launch MySQL Workbench, nothing happens on-screen & 2 application log errors are generated. One is a very generic KERNEL32 event, and the other is .NET related:

**Application: MySQLWorkbench.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException Stack: at MySQL.GUI.Workbench.Program.Main(System.String[])**

Most of the resolutions I've found online relate to [missing prerequisites](https://dev.mysql.com/resources/wb62_prerequisites.html), which include

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015

I have installed both of these on the machine but am still seeing the same behavior.  Can anyone suggest anything else to try?

Comment: Try the latest version (6.3.9 atm).

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to MySQL Workbench 6.3.9 resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

i installed MySQL Workbench 8.0.19 and I encountered the same error. When I installed the following package, my problem was solved and MySQL Workbench started.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
(My operating system is 64 bit and I downloaded->  x64: vc_redist.x64.exe)